# 謎のクリックイベントが呼ばれる

Tags: monaca, jquery

monacaで初のアプリ習作を作っています。
16x20程度のテーブルを作り、セルをタップしたらフォーカスを移すという機能を実装しようとしている最中で、急に思った通りの動作をしてくれなくなってしまいました。
具体的にいうと、indexが-1のtd要素からクリックイベントが呼ばれたきり、それ以降クリックに反応しなくなってしまいます。
あれ・・・さっきまで動いてたのにナンデ・・・。
いろいろ試しているのですが行き詰っています。どなたか解決策ご存じありませんか？

```
function cellClick(){
    console.log("clicked"+$("td").index(this)+"/"+$("td").length);
//ここで"clicked-1/352"のログが出て、それ以降クリックに反応しなくなる。
    $(".focus").removeClass("focus");
    $(this).addClass("focus");
}

$(function(){
    console.log("load complete.");
    showTable();//テーブルを構築して表示
    $("td").click(cellClick());
});
```

Comment: 対応するHTML部分も提示していただけますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$("td").click(cellClick()); は間違いでは？

jQuery.click() の引数は function ですので、cellClickという関数がfunctionを返すのであれば意味は通りますが、cellClick自体をクリックイベントのコールバック関数として登録するのであれば、
$("td").click(cellClick);
とする必要がありますよね。

"clicked-1/352"のログが吐き出されたのは、$("td").click(cellClick());を実行した時に
cellClick関数が呼ばれたため、と思います。